# error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: gradle, flutter, androidx

I had a flutter app working fine, then I thought I'd upgrade all my plugins to androidX, and everything work fine before I decided to add firebase_messaging, I've tried version 4,5, none worked, keep throwing that error as if i'm on the wrong version. And I also tried `flutter packages pub cache repair` no luck. there's many issues related on github, however they all got closed with people still complaining the fix is not working.
here's my gradle looks like

```js
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '3'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.sggo.uni"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // ndk {
        //     abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        // }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

```js
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                details.useVersion "15.+"
            }
            
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
>                                 ^
>     symbol:   class InstanceIdResult
>     location: package com.google.firebase.iid
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
>                 new OnCompleteListener() {
>                                        ^
>     symbol:   class InstanceIdResult
>     location: class FirebaseMessagingPlugin
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
>                                                        ^
>     symbol: class InstanceIdResult
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
>             .getInstanceId()
>             ^
>     symbol:   method getInstanceId()
>     location: class FirebaseInstanceId
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
>                 new OnCompleteListener() {
>                                        ^
>     symbol:   class InstanceIdResult
>     location: class FirebaseMessagingPlugin
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
>                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
>                                                        ^
>     symbol: class InstanceIdResult
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
>             .getInstanceId()
>             ^
>     symbol:   method getInstanceId()
>     location: class FirebaseInstanceId
>   /Users/test/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.0.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:39: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>     @Override

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult is deprecated and no longer available.
Thus in order to get token from firebase now you have to use.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
      if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
        return;
      }

      // Get new FCM registration token
      String token = task.getResult();

      // Log and toast
      String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
      Log.d(TAG, msg);
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

below change solved my problem

from :

```
ext {
 firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
}
```

to:

```
ext {
 firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
}
```

Comment: where do we add the above? @Lord

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by using this exactbuild gradle and google-services version number combo, hope it some how helps you

```js
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```